# Do you need Visual C 2013 to compile Unreal 4?

Tags: unreal-4

Do you need a specific version of Visual C to compile Unreal 4? If so, why?
I read in [a lot of places](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/CompilingProjects/index.html):

> Please make sure you are running Visual Studio 2013 Professional or Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop installed before proceeding. If you are using Mac, make sure to have Xcode installed.

Why would you need that version? What is wrong with version 2010?

Comment: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/1769/is-visual-studio-2010-supported.html

Yup, you need 2012 or 2013, preferably 2013. But remember afaik you don't need to compile it in order to use it for various purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons could include solution/project file versions (older versions could just not open it at all), but most probably main reason is C++ compiler version which is tigthly coupled with version of VS (AFAIK you can't update VC++ compiler, but continue to use older version of VS IDE). [Latest versions of VC++ compilers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) are significantly improved in terms of `C++11` standard support which is, most probably, used by UE4.